# how to insert an if check in an insert

Tags: trigger, insert, postgresql-9.5

I have an after insert at the statment level, which must insert the positive or negative result in an attribute based on the count of the values of other attributes. But control structures cannot be inserted at that point. How can I do? Thanks to those who respond.

```
insert into public.votazione(

...
esito,
...)
values(
...
if(new.favorevoli=new.votanti+1 and (select count(*) from voto where 
new.data=voto.data and (voto.ddl=new.ddl or voto.mozione=new.mozione)))
       then new.esito='approvato';
       else new.esito='non approvato';
       end if;, --esito,
```

function trigger

```
(TG_OP='INSERT')
 then   
       insert into public.votazione(
       mozione,
       ddl,
       codice,
       favorevoli,
       votanti,
       contrari,
       astenuti,
       esito,
       tipo_assemblea,
       seduta_numero,
       data,
       assenti,
       missione)
 values(voto.mozione,--<>null then(select codice from mozione where codice=voto.mozione)
       -- else mozione=null,--mozione, 
 (/*select titolo from ddl where titolo*/voto.ddl), --ddl, 
 (select codice from ddl where ddl.titolo=voto.ddl), --codice, 
 (select count(*) from voto where new.data=voto.data and
                               voto_palese='favorevole'), --favorevoli, 
 (new.favorevoli+new.contrari+new.astenuti), --votanti, 
 (select voto_palese from voto where data=new.data and voto_palese='contrario'), --contrari, 
 (select voto_palese from voto where data=new.data and voto_palese='astenuto'), -- astenuti, 
 if(new.favorevoli=new.votanti+1 and (select count(*) from voto where new.data=voto.data and (voto.ddl=new.ddl or voto.mozione=new.mozione)))
       then new.esito='approvato';
       else new.esito='non approvato';
       end if;, --esito, 
 (select tipo_assemblea from ordine_del_giorno_ass_cam_e_sen where data=voto.data), --tipo_assemblea, 
 (select seduta_numero from ordine_del_giorno_ass_cam_e_sen where data=voto.data), --seduta_numero, 
 (SELECT data from ordine_del_giorno_ass_cam_e_sen where  
   new.tipo_assemblea=ordine_del_giorno_ass_cam_e_sen.tipo_assemblea and ordine_del_giorno_ass_cam_e_sen.data=voto.data), --data, 
 (select count(*) from timbratura_giornaliera where presenze='Assente' and new.data=timbratura_giornaliera.data), --assenti, 
 (select count(*) from timbratura_giornaliera where presenze='In missione' and new.data=timbratura_giornaliera.data) -- missione
 );
```

enter code here

```
CREATE TABLE public.votazione
(
 mozione character(10),
 ddl character varying(500) NOT NULL,
 codice character(10),
 favorevoli integer,
 votanti integer,
 contrari integer,
 astenuti integer,
  esito character(20) NOT NULL,
 tipo_assemblea character varying(6) NOT NULL,
 seduta_numero integer,
 data date NOT NULL,
 assenti integer,
 missione integer,
 CONSTRAINT votazione_pkey PRIMARY KEY (esito, data, tipo_assemblea),
 CONSTRAINT approvazionevotoasscamesenddlfkey FOREIGN KEY (ddl, codice)
  REFERENCES public.ddl (titolo, codice) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
 CONSTRAINT approvazionevotoasscamesenmozionefkey FOREIGN KEY (mozione)
  REFERENCES public.mozione (codice) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
 CONSTRAINT votazione_data_fkey FOREIGN KEY (data, tipo_assemblea, 
 seduta_numero)
  REFERENCES public.ordine_del_giorno_ass_cam_e_sen (data, tipo_assemblea, 
 seduta_numero) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
 CONSTRAINT votazione_favorevoli_contrari_assenti_missione_astenuti_ddl_key 
 UNIQUE (favorevoli, contrari, assenti, missione, astenuti, ddl),
 CONSTRAINT votazione_favorevoli_contrari_astenuti_codice_assenti_missi_key 
 UNIQUE (favorevoli, contrari, astenuti, codice, assenti, missione),
 CONSTRAINT votazionedatacodicekey UNIQUE (data, codice),
 CONSTRAINT votazionedataddlkey UNIQUE (data, ddl),
 CONSTRAINT votazionedatamozionekey UNIQUE (data, mozione)
  )


CREATE TRIGGER inserimento_votazione 
AFTER INSERT ON public.voto 
FOR EACH 
STATEMENT 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.inserimento_votazione();
```

the trigger must add the tuple 'voto' in the vote table and insert the sum in the 'votazione', so it does not click for each row, but must be a trigger at the instruction level.

```
CREATE TABLE public.voto
(
data date NOT NULL,
parlamentare character varying(100) NOT NULL,
voto_palese character(20) NOT NULL,
ddl character varying(500),
mozione character varying(300),
CONSTRAINT voto_pkey PRIMARY KEY (data, parlamentare, voto_palese),
CONSTRAINT voto_data_parlamentare_voto_palese_ddl_key UNIQUE (data, 
parlamentare, voto_palese, ddl),
CONSTRAINT voto_mozione_data_parlamentare_voto_palese_key UNIQUE (mozione, 
data, parlamentare, voto_palese)
 )
  WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
 );
 ALTER TABLE public.voto
  OWNER TO postgres;
 GRANT ALL ON TABLE public.voto TO postgres;
 GRANT ALL ON TABLE public.voto TO public;
```

Comment: `case when ...`?

Comment: There is no case. is a trigger that triggers after being inserted into a table, and reacts by inserting data into another table. I report the function to you. One of the values to be entered is 'approved' if the vote count exceeds the majority, new.favorevoli = new.votanti + 1.

Comment: I added the function code, now it's clearer? have I explained myself?

Comment: `create table` statements might help.  Also, what is your Business Requirements?

Comment: I'm a university student, it's a project for an exam

Comment: this is what @a_horse_with_no_name meant: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE It can definitely be used in your `INSERT`.  Also, for the sake of the question, it would make sense to strip down the example to the minimal size with which your issue still can be explained clearly.  The above is a bit frightening, especially if one doesn't speak Italian.

Comment: ok i'll try as you say, thanks, i've added clarifications, i hope this is clearer